# Package does not exist error after upgrading to visual studio 2019 build 16.2

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

We have a Xamarin.Forms project that was created a couple of years ago and after upgrading to the latest build of Visual Studio 2019 (16.2) we are getting nearly 100 errors like the following when building the android version of the project: error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient does not exist

I checked with a colleague who was using Visual Studio build 16.1.3 and the android project built fine but after upgrading their Visual Studio 2019 to the 16.2 build they now get the same problem too.  The iOS project continues to build fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what to try? I found a bunch of older posts that suggested adding items in the Android SDK manager but none of these changes helped me.
Failing that does anyone know of a way for me to revert my Visual Studio install back to 16.1.3?

Comment: First of all, you can delete the `bin` and `obj` folder in your project(PCL, android , IOS ), then rebuild your project, then build your project, if this issue is disappear, then if this issue is disappear, you could try to repair your VS in the Visual studio installer?(click the `More`, choose the `Repair`).

Comment: First, you should follow the @LeonLu-MSFT suggestions, but if notting works, you can try to Unload and Reload the PCL and Android projects, so they reload the packages again, also you can try to clear the package cache, but just do that as a last resource, i did that and just caused more problems with other packages, the Unload and Reload did the trick for me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Leon and Ricardo.  Unfortunately still no luck though.  I deleted the bin and obj folders in all three projects, unloaded and reloaded the projects (via the context menu), cleared out the packages folder and repaired Visual Studio.  Clearing out the packages folder did cause other issues as you suggested it would but I solved them and was still left with these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated all NuGet packages? Did it help to move to VS 16.3.5? Have you checked the dependencies of your NuGet packages?
I am having issues with an activity being placed outside of application. It seems like the Google Ads/Admob implementation in Xamarin apps is a source of troubles. Net Core version also seems like a good place to check for a solution.